# What do you call a "schizophrenia attack"?

Tags: expressions, terminology, medical

Attack as in *panic attack*. I don't know the term for it.

Comment: People have "acute exacerbations" and remissions of schizophrenia. If there is psychosis, they can have episodes. There are no attacks. "Onset" for the first symptoms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

schizophrenic (or psychotic) **episode**

> People often have **episodes of schizophrenia**, during which their
>   symptoms are particularly severe, followed by periods where they
>   experience few or no positive symptoms. This is known as acute
>   schizophrenia.
>   [Boots WebMD](http://www.webmd.boots.com/mental-health/schizophrenia-directory)

Note that it usually occurs as a **psychotic episode** as that is one symptom of schizophrenia.

> For example, schizophrenia can be long-term, but most people can make
>   a good recovery, and about a quarter only have a single **psychotic
>   episode**.
>   [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/Psychosis/Pages/Introduction.aspx)

Comment: Also called a *psychotic break*.

Comment: Why is the second  link called *Boots* when the website is the NHS (National Health Service)? The first has *Boots* as its sponsor, or so it seems to me,  but the actual website is *WebMD*

Comment: Careless of me. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatically, this is called a "schizophrenic break". This is the layman's term functionally equivalent to "panic attack" but with reference to schizophrenia. "Schizophrenic break" use differs from the layman's use of "schizophrenic episode" in that an episode may start slowly and build up gradually, may be of indefinite duration, and may be characterized by a greater or lesser degree of symptom intensity, while a break refers to the sudden, usually short-term onset of acute schizophrenia symptoms, just as a "panic attack" is the sudden, usually short-term onset of acute symptoms of an underlying panic disorder that may have preceded and may persist after the attack.

> The term "schizophrenic break" refers to an episode of acute psychosis in someone with schizophrenia.

(From ["Schizophrenic Break"](http://www.schizophrenic.com/articles/schizophrenia/schizophrenic-break) at *Schizophrenic.com*.)

The term is also applied generally to any psychosis, in the form "psychotic break", but the specific application to schizophrenia is common:

> This experience of the schizophrenic break is akin to Dante’s Inferno, before he climbed through Purgatory and on to Paradise.

(From ["Navigating a Psychotic Break"](http://www.schizlife.com/navigating-a-psychotic-break/) at *schiz life*.)